# How to convert M3U PLAYLIST TO JSON OBJECTS IN IONIC ( ANGULAR )?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

i need to build json api from m3u playlist to my android application built by ionic ,

i tried IPTV to json npm package but not work , example :

m3u playlist :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="tf1.fr" tvg-name="TF1 HD" tvg-logo="http://atlaspro.to:80/images/eae78e001f68ca604b6a86f41152dfb6.png" group-title="FRANCE HD",TF1 HD
http://apcdn.top:8000/live/77497490475602056/1593574628/7819.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="france2.fr" tvg-name="FRANCE 2 HD" tvg-logo="http://appicons.in/picons/PICONS-BOUQUET-FRANCEHD/FRANCE2.png" group-title="FRANCE HD",FRANCE 2 HD
http://apcdn.top:8000/live/77497490475602056/1593574628/7824.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="france3.fr" tvg-name="FRANCE 3 HD" tvg-logo="http://appicons.in/picons/PICONS-BOUQUET-FRANCEHD/FRANCE3.png" group-title="FRANCE HD",FRANCE 3 HD
http://apcdn.top:8000/live/77497490475602056/1593574628/7823.ts
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="canalplus.fr" tvg-name="CANAL+ HD" tvg-logo="http://appicons.in/picons/PICONS-BOUQUET-FRANCEHD/CANAL+.png" group-title="FRANCE HD",CANAL+ HD
http://apcdn.top:8000/live/77497490475602056/1593574628/7809.ts
```

output :

```
[
    {
        "channel_name": " TF1 HD",
        "img": "",
        "group": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    {
        "channel_name": "  SBT - TV Jornal (PE)",
        "img": "https://listaiptv.gratis/logos/imagens/sbt.png",
        "group": "Variedades",
        "video_url": "http://evpp.mm.uol.com.br/ne10/ne10.smil/playlist.m3u8"
    },
    {
        "channel_name": " SBT Interior SP",
        "img": "https://listaiptv.gratis/logos/imagens/sbt.png",
        "group": "Variedades",
        "video_url": "https://5a1c76baf08c0.streamlock.net/z343-live/z343/playlist.m3u8"
    },
]
```

Comment: You can try this new package ;)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/m3u-parser-generator